# Bash: How to keep line if number in second column is greater than 3?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

What is the best way to keep line if number in second column (separated by space) is greater than 3?

And I MUST NOT use awk or sed! -.-

Input:

```
2 2 asd 132ds
1 4 sdf 234sd
1 3 gfd 654gh
1 1 rtz 543jh
1 10 uio 654iu
```

Output:

```
1 4 sdf 234sd
1 10 uio 654iu
```

Comment: I've remove the awk and sed tags, as you explicitly don't want to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
while read -r i j k; do [ "$j" -gt 3 ] && echo "$i $j $k"; done <file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` to filter out unwanted requirements

```
$ cat file
2 2 asd 132ds
1 4 sdf 234sd
1 3 gfd 654gh
1 1 rtz 543jh
1 10 uio 654iu
```

```
$ egrep -v '^[^.]+ [1-3] ' file
1 4 sdf 234sd
1 10 uio 654iu
```

Comment: I like this idea, but the regex is wrong, and will find a lone numeral 1-3 in any culumn. A better regex is `'^[^ ]+ +[1-3] '` (the quotes are not part of the regex proper, but the shell requires the regex to be quoted).

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, didn't realize that part was modified with edit as well. I thought only `egrep` was changed to `grep -E`. Appreciate the edit! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Using while loop

```
while read line; do if [ $(echo $line|cut -d " " -f2) -gt 3 ]; then echo $line; fi; done < testfile.txt
```